# How to subtract two rows from one another if they have they share a value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently working in a database with the following structure:

```
Var | Value | ID
--------------
  A |   1   | 1
  B |   2   | 1
  C |   3   | 1
  A |   2   | 2
  B |   4   | 2
  C |   6   | 2
```

What I am trying to achieve is to subtract the value of Var C from the other Var's (B and C) sharing the same ID as Var C. In this case the output would be:

```
Var | Value | ID
--------------
  A |  -2   | 1
  B |  -1   | 1
  C |   3   | 1
  A |  -4   | 2
  B |  -2   | 2
  C |   6   | 2
```

To be honest I have absolutely no idea how to start on achieving this. I am familiar with many other programming languages, but SQL is still a challenge with difficult/specific queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a self join:

```
select t1.var,
       case when t1.var = 'C' then t1.value
            else t1.value - t2.value
       end as value,
       t1.id
from tablename t1
  join tablename t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
where t2.var = 'C'
```

Note that `value` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so it should be delimited as `"Value"`.

Comment: Seems like the correct answer, but I would be inclined to use a `left join` in case some ids are missing `c` values.

Comment: No problem to convert to `LEFT JOIN`, but OP has to describe which value to be returned in the case no C var?

Comment: It should be the case that every ID has a C var, but I'll keep this in mind in case there are any problems!

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-analyse the "C" Values and then use this to remove them?

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    [Var] VARCHAR(1),
    Value INT,
    ID INT);
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'A', 1, 1;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'B', 2, 1;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'C', 3, 1;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'A', 2, 2;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'B', 4, 2;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'C', 6, 2;

WITH CValues AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        Value
    FROM
        @Data
    WHERE
        [Var] = 'C')
SELECT
    d.[Var],
    CASE WHEN d.[Var] != 'C' THEN d.Value - c.Value ELSE d.Value END AS Value,
    d.ID
FROM
    @Data d
    LEFT JOIN CValues c ON c.ID = d.ID;
```

...but yes, a self-join is probably a better solution:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    [Var] VARCHAR(1),
    Value INT,
    ID INT);
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'A', 1, 1;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'B', 2, 1;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'C', 3, 1;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'A', 2, 2;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'B', 4, 2;
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 'C', 6, 2;

SELECT
    d.[Var],
    CASE WHEN d.[Var] != 'C' THEN d.Value - c.Value ELSE d.Value END AS Value,
    d.ID
FROM
    @Data d
    LEFT JOIN @Data c ON c.[Var] = 'C' AND c.ID = d.ID;
```